# How to check for website changes and sending an alert in case of a change via Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, monitoring, selenium-ide

I like to go to a website (lets call it website1) and click on a link on website1 (so Im on website 2 now), and then receive a text or alert if there has been a change from last version of website2 (lets say compare to the version that it was 15 mins ago).

Does anyone know if it is possible via Selenium IDE?

On another note, there are a lot of monitoring website that does record the changes and send the alert, but non of them (to the best of my knowledge) has the feature to be able to click on a link and go through the next website (website2 in my case). And in my case, there is no way to get to website2 without going to website1 first.

If it helps, I also know a little bit of python.

Any suggestion and help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why do you have to go through website 1? Is the link always the same? Maybe you could configure a monitoring website to point to website 2 directly, using the URL from the link.

Comment: It does not let me go to the website 2 directly, when I copy and paste the website2 link it redirect me to the website1 and ask me to click on the link of website 2. even using the URL it again redirect me to website1 after pasting the link of website2, so I guess that is a security thing